# Send Message between background.js and event.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to have my `background.js` receive information from my `event.js` (they are both running as background scripts) or at least allow `background.js` to use a function from `event.js`.

---

Why do I want to do this:

I have set up my code so that `background.js` handles the main tasks.

My `content-scripts` need saved information now and then from `chrome.storage` so they need to send a message to a background page.

In order to keep the code organized, I create another background page called `event.js` with `chrome.runtime.onMessage` listener and all the functions for doing the requested tasks coming from the content scripts.

Then I realize that `background.js` also needs to do some of those same functions, so in order to not duplicate the code, I have `background.js` use `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` to `event.js`.

The expected result is that `event.js` communicates with `background.js` as successfully as the `content-scripts` do.

The actual result is that the `event.js` never receives any messages from `background.js`.

---

I've read the documentation on background pages and on message passing trying to find the answer or a hint.

**Is there some reason these two pages cannot communicate through messagePassing?
If so, how can I successfully pass information or functions between these two pages?**

Comment: **There's only one background page** so all background scripts run inside that one page. You can see it in devtools for the background page. They all run in the same global context and share the same DOM. You don't need to send messages inside the page to pass data. The API won't let you do it. Just invoke your function(s) directly or via `require` if you use it.

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh I see! But now when I try to invoke an `event.js` function from `background.js`, it says that function is not defined and it appears that it's attempting to invoke it before `event.js` loads.

Comment: Good, now you have something to work on. Use devools for the background page to set breakpoints and inspect the variables etc. You can press F5 or run `location.reload()` to quickly reload the background page so it'll trigger breakpoints you've set and you'll see what happens when it loads.

Comment: See also [What is the difference between background pages and background scripts?](//stackoverflow.com/q/51213241) - as you can see the scripts are standard DOM scripts which run sequentially in the specified order just like any other page script loaded using the standard `<script src="foo"></script>`

Comment: @wOxxOm Great, thank you. Totally get it now. I simply listed event.js first in the manifest to ensure it loads first. If you could copy your comments into an answer, then I can upvote and accept it. (BTW I noticed you answer often in comments and many chrome-extension questions are left with an appearance of 0 answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All background scripts, if defined in the same list in the manifest file, will see everything that is defined.

So, if you add them to the manifest in the "correct order", the last script will see all `var`s and `function`s from the previous scripts.

If you're using the same function in both `background.js` and `event.js`, maybe you could create a `background_funcs.js` simply to define all common functions and put it as the first in your manifest.

This way the others will see everything defined in it.

Comment: With that suggestion about `background_funcs.js`, I've been able to greatly improve the organization of my background scripts. If WOxxOm doesn't create his own answer soon, I'll accept this answer instead.

Comment: Fair enough :))